# $dirty with ng-model-options = { updateOn : 'blur' }

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form name="angForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name1" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
    <span ng-show="angForm.name1.$dirty">* Will be updated to model
                only after this text box is blurred.
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" class="form-control" ng-model="person.lastName"
        ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'blur'}" ng-disabled="!edit"
        placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>
</form>
```

The above code just have a text box with a span message, which I expect to appear once the user interacts (i.e., types) with the text box, but the model must be updated with the view value only when the user leaves the text box.

But, the span message is not displaying as soon as the interaction happens, it gets displayed only when the user leaves the text box.

Can anyone please explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Is the above code inside <form> tags with the name 'angForm'?

Comment: I am seeing the span as soon as I interact with the field, is this not correct? http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/suxc48aj/

Comment: Be aware that JSFiddle uses old Angular version which does not support `ngModelOptions`. I think it is impossible to achieve what you want without some custom directive / additional logic.

Comment: yes that's correct. Am sorry, but not getting it right here :(

Comment: Am sorry I cant get you. $dirty expects for a change in view only right? Does $dirty is set only for a model change?

Comment: `$dirty` is set by `ngModel`, which is bound to an event you define in `ngModelOptions`. You have set to act upon *blur*, so this flag will be set only after the input field loses the focus.

Comment: What is interesting is that I have tried to workaround your "issue" by using `ngChange` (see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/funewosavu/1/edit?html,output)). However it seems that this also takes `ngModelOptions` into account, which is undocumented behaviour and can be considered as a bug (judging on the `ngChange` documentation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.. We can do this only using onChange of js?. And also dirty always goes with the updateOn event right?

Comment: Just curious - do you need to use `ngModelOptions` at all? Because angular works on `change` [events by default](http://jsbin.com/qegufevigu/1/edit?html,output)... so maybe you just misinterpreted some example / tutorial.

Comment: Ha ha..Am a newbie to angular js.. I just wanna explore all the options available in it. So just wanna dig deeper .Thanks a lot for your time.